# installing extensible service proxy on Ubuntu in Google Compute Engine

Tags: ubuntu, google-compute-engine

I'm working on setting up endpoints for my GCE instance(s). I have followed the "quickstart for endpoints on compute engine" but I cannot install the "endpoints-runtime" package. The error I get is "E: Unable to locate package endpoints-runtime".

I have checked /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-endpoints.list and it contains:

```
deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-endpoints-xenial main
```

I performed a `sudo apt-get update` to refresh the package directory. How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the repository name changed. You need to do the following on your instance:

```
export CLOUD_ENDPOINTS_REPO="google-cloud-endpoints-jessie"
```

The docs have now been updated:  https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/get-started-compute-engine#running_the_extensible_service_proxy